# Can the size of the workspace switcher applet be changed?

Tags: xfce, workspace-switcher

At the moment, I only have 4 workspaces but the workspace switcher is taking up half of my panel. Is there a way to resize it or cause it to take up less space (other than increasing the number of rows)? I just want each workspace to take up less horizontal space in the switcher.

I am running Xfce on 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the size of the `Workspace Switcher` in Xfce4, we need to change it in the Panel settings.

Click on:

*Whisker Menu -> Settings -> Panel -> Items -> Workspace Switcher -> (Gear to edit selected item)*

[image]

In the Workspace Switcher configuration, uncheck `Show miniature view`

[image]

Then your Workspace Switcher should look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. I like the thumbnail views, it's just that they seem much larger than in Ubuntu 12.04. I was hoping for a way to simply resize it and scale down the thumbnails.